# Self referencing dynamic SQL pivot query returning unwanted results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know there are better ways to design the table but this is just an example of what I need

I just can't seem to get the results I'm looking for

Table and data:

[image]

Query:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(columnType) 
            FROM [Values]
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

SET @query = 'SELECT ' + @cols + ' FROM 
        (
            SELECT value, columnType
            FROM [Values]
       ) x
        PIVOT 
        (
            MAX(value)
            FOR columnType IN (' + @cols + ')
        ) p '

EXECUTE(@query)
```

Result I get:

[image]

Results I want

```
Product    Item    SubItem

   A        A A     A A A
   A        A B     A A B
   B        B A      NULL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query can be easily resolved using `join`s for two levels:

```
select v.value as Product, vi.value as Item, vsi.value as Subitem
from [Values] v left join
     [Values] vi
     on vi.column_type = 'Item' and vi.parent_id = v.id left join
     [Values] vsi
     on vsi.column_type = 'Sub Item' and vsi.parent_id = v.id
where v.column_type = 'Product';
```

If you have an unknown number of levels, then you can expand on this query using dynamic SQL.

Comment: It wasn't exactly the answer I was looking for but it will work. Codeing the dynamic sql is a bit more messy